# Delphi, class not found

Tags: delphi

After a voted closing of this Thread/Question, i had my Problem fixed.
But i still want to give it a shot to re-write my Problem/Question, so others could benefit from it. So here i go:

### Main Problem:

I´ve got a Project using two external Dependencies. Those Dependencies represent Elements which are Visually shown in the Form-Editor.
The Exact Problem is, that the "Main" Project can´t seem to find these Dependencies, therefore the Visual Representation of the Form can´t get generated.

This Error gets Displayed with the Message "Class  can´t be found.", and therefore i can choose to either ignore the Error - which results in deleting all occurences of the missing class in the opened form - or i can cancel the opening of the Form-Editor.

I also read somewhere - correct me if i´m wrong - that these Dependencies in my case are called Units in Delphi.

I got the Sourcecode to these Dependencies, which in my case are a **.dcu*, a **.pas* and a **.dpk* file.

So the Question would be:
**How does one add external Units to a Delphi Project?**

### The Path to the Solution:

The first hint to solve my problem was given by @fpiette:

> But a developer can write his own component. To be usable by Delphi IDE, this component needs to be "installed". That is build in a package (A special kind of project in a .dpk file)

So now i needed to search for a **.dpk* file, which i "conveniently" have for each dependency.
After a little bit of further investigation, i found [this](https://www.delphipower.xyz/guide_6/installing_component_packages.html) - or more specifically:

> The directory where you store the .dcp file—and the .dcu files, if they are included with the distribution—must be in the Delphi Library Path.

Now i knew, i also need to add the Path of these Sources to my Library.

The last step missing was now only to "add" these Files to my Project. After playing a bit around with the IDE, i found the Prompt "Install Component", under the "Components" Tab.

In the upcoming Wizard i selected to install the Unit into a new package, and selected the **.pas* File for the Dependency. The next Windows asked for a "Name" in form of a **.dpk* File, which i also have in the sourcefolder.

So after selecting the **.dpk* File, my Project was converted into a Projectgroup, and had the newly added Dependency as a second Project besides my "Main" Project.

So i did these Steps with all Dependencies needed, compiled all Dependencies and now the IDE wouldn´t show the Error anymore but open the Form-Editor correctly.

I also want to mention why it didn´t work for me earlier - or at least what i think what my Error was:
In the Described "Install Component"-Wizard, i selected the *.dcu file instead of the *.pas File. The Dependency was still added to my ProjectGroup, but didn´t solve my main Problem.

So i "reverted" back to my starting-point, and selected the *.pas file instead of the *.dcu file.

I hope my Problem is now better explained and formatted, im open for criticism!

Thanks for your help earlier, and have a nice day!

Comment: You can't learn what you need like this, with an SO question. It takes more than that. Significant knowledge is required. You will need to adjust your expectations accordingly.

Comment: This requires a [mcve].  Telling us a story about what your code does has an exceedingly low probability of effectively communicating the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you named "Picture" and designated as .dfm file is actually named a "form".

When you open a form, the IDE make a visual representation of it and for that need all components referenced in it. There are hundreds of components delivered with Delphi (Well know such a button, edit, combobox and much much more).

But a developer can write his own component. To be usable by Delphi IDE, this component needs to be "installed". That is build in a package (A special kind of project in a .dpk file). That package must be compiled and the installed (right click in project manager).

If a component used by a form is not installed, you get the error you said. Do NOT click "ignore" in the messagebox but click "Cancel". Then close the form, install the component and reopen the form. If you click "ignore", then IDE will REMOVE that component and your application will be broken (Do NOT save it then).

You have been given the source code, so search for a .dpk file (or several). Then open it, compile it and install it. Only then you can open the form giving the error.

By the way, you should really buy a good book about Delphi. There are a lot of Delphi books. I suggest you start with [Object Pascal Handbook](https://www.marcocantu.com/objectpascalhandbook/)

Comment: Doesn't seem to answer a specific question that was asked, because there was no specific question asked.

Comment: The OP ask - between the lines - how to solve all the errors he has. He is completely new to Delphi and doesn't use the correct wording to describe the problem. Maybe also a problem with English language. And he is new with StackOverflow so be kind with him.

Comment: @exobite Does my answer solved your problem? If yes, please mark it as accepted. And also reformulate your post so that it becomes a specific question. Exposing a problem is not considered as a question by some peoples. That's the rules of StackOverflow. If my answer didn't solve your problem, you'd better reformulate it more clearly without forgetting to add a specific question to comply with StackOverflow rules.

Comment: I edited my beggining post at //Edit2.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Having compiled the package is not enough: you must install it. For that, right click on the package project and select "install" entry. Then you can open the form, unless another component is missing). By the way, instead of adding at the end of your message, you can update the content in a manner that the next reader immediately the question correctly formulated. The idea of StackOverflow is that other's problem will solve my problems. High quality question is important. Poor quality questions are useless and will be closed (that is make invisible).

Comment: Closing a question pass thru a vote and you already have 2 close votes. On the next one, your question will be closed. You urgently need to clean up things...

Comment: @fpiette If there are problems with the question that warrant close votes, you should not answer it. Please understand that this site is not about providing one-to-one help, it's primarily about building a resource of useful topics, useful for others.